# Having trouble adding objects to JList to display on scrollpane

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I've worked at creating a defaultlistcellrender for an object that i have made but so far it's proving very difficult to add objects to JList. I am attaching the code for any suggestions. Thanks!

```
public class JTabbedPaneTester extends JFrame 
{
    private List<Human> members = new ArrayList<Human>();
    private JList newbie = new JList();
    private DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();

    public JTabbedPaneTester() throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        super("JTabbedPane Demo");
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(); 
        JPanel gladiator = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(gladiator); 
        tabbedPane.addTab("Gladiator", null, Gladiator, "");
        Box listOfPlayers = Box.createVerticalBox();
        listOfPlayers.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(100,100)));
        listOfPlayers.setBorder(new TitledBorder("List of Players"));
        JScrollPane playerViewer = new JScrollPane();
        playerViewer.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        listOfPlayers.add(playerViewer);
        JButton AddIndividual = new JButton("Add a Player");
        listOfPlayers.add(addIndividual);
        gladiator.add(listOfPlayers);
    final HumanListModel modelx = new HumanListModel();
    final JTable newbiex = new JTable(modelx);
    newbiex.setDefaultRenderer(Human.class, new HumanRenderer());
    playerViewer.setViewportView(newbiex);

    addIndividual.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
                    Human temp;
                try {
                    temp = new Human();     
                    modelx.addHuman(temp);
                        } 
                    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }       
                    }
        });
        add(tabbedPane); 
    }
}
```

Here is the renderer someone on here nicely helped me with

```
class HumanRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer

        {
           public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
              int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) 
           {


              JLabel label = new JLabel(); 
              if (value != null) 
              {
                 Human human = (Human) value;
                 label.setText(human.getSurname() + ", " + human.getFirstName());
              }

              return label;
           }
        }
```

Comment: I'm not even going to look at the code until you fix the variable names. Variable names should not start with an upper case character. Also don't leave a blank line between every line of code. Too much scrolling is required to see all the code at one glance.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) A single blank line of white space is always enough.   3) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently. 4) Don't extend frame or other top level containers.  Instead create & use an instance of one.

Comment: You're shadowing the model variable by redeclaring it in the constructor.

Comment: I can't really find the part where you use your `HumanRenderer`. Why do you have it if you are not using it? Should be something like `newbie.setDefaultRenderer(Human.class, new HumanRenderer());`

Comment: Ok I changed all the variables to begin with lowercase letters. Thanks for letting me know. Hey Daniel where do insert that line of code? Also I don't know what an SSCCE is.

Comment: *"I don't know what an SSCCE is."*  That is why I *linked* to the article.

Comment: Yea I just clicked on it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add objects to the model and not to the jlist panel. The add the you use for components. Try to get the model from jlist and use addElement of the model.

Comment: No need to validate or repaint when adding objects to the model.

Comment: Thanks, someway or another I most likely have to use if I change the panel content. But I think that in here it is not needed because of the listeners in the model right?

Comment: Correct. The model should call fireXXX methods when data changes. 1+

Comment: +1, for adding Objects to the `model`, but as Hovercraft has already pointed out you have 2 model variable defined. Get rid of the instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `DefaultListModel` which uses a `DefaultListCellRenderer`. I don't see any part in your code that actually makes use of your `HumanRenderer`. You have to write your own Model.

```
public class HumanListModel extends DefaultListModel
{
    private ArrayList<Human> data;

    public HumanListModel()
    {
        super();
        data = new ArrayList<Human>();
    }

    public void addHuman(Human h)
    {
       // add new human to the model
       data.add(h);
       fireTableStructureChanged();
    }

    public void removeHuman(Human h)
    {
        data.remove(h);
        fireTableStructureChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount()
    {
        // the number of columns you want to display
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount()
    {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col)
    {
        return (row < data.size()) ? data.get(row) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int col)
    {
        return "Human";
    }

    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int col)
    {
        return Human.class;
    }
}
```

For your `JTable` you just have to set the `HumanListModel` and define your renderer. All changes to your data should afterwards directely made at the model. Ergo use: `model.addHuman()` and `model.removeHuman()`. They fire the necessary Events which the `JTable` listens for in order to repaint.

```
HumanListModel model = new HumanListModel();
JTable newbies = new JTable(model);
newbies.setDefaultRenderer(Human.class, new HumanRenderer());
```

I hope it works...

Comment: Thanks I will definitely try and get it to work, I don't know the coding for custom cell renderers too well that's why I'm having such trouble with it.

Comment: No you don't have to write your own model. The DefaultListModel will work fine, but you do have to set your custom renderer on the JList.

Comment: Hey Daniel, unfortunately I'm still unable to get it to work. I want it to simply add a new randomly-generated human each time the button is clicked. What could be the problem with JList or JTable unable to display the human object contents despite it already being declared?